# How can I restore from a snapshot on AWS RDS-Preview?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

This is RDS-Preview in Ohio, on a Postgres database.

My database randomly shut itself off. It was serving a read-only web app, there was no write traffic. This is already frustrating. I have two snapshots, one marked as "automated" and one as "manual". I attempt to export either to S3, but this option is greyed out. I attempt to restore the database. The drop downs for "DB Engine" and "license" both only allow one option, postgres (as expected). I pick the same instance class that it was (db.t2.micro), but I just get this:

> RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.micro, Engine=postgres, EngineVersion=12.20191002, LicenseModel=postgresql-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 8cfc0826-9664-40d1-99f6-3f40977f5aec)

I try a random selection of database instance classes, none of them allow me to restore the snapshot. If anyone could point me towards this "documentation" that describes which instance class I'm permitted to use to restore my database snapshot which is apparently Postgres 12.20191002, I believe that would solve the problem. I can find this documentation for RDS, but not RDS Preview. RDS doesn't even have Postgres 12 yet.

How can I get this data back? I just want access to the snapshot, by any means. :(

Comment: Are you referring to [Working with the Database Preview Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#working-with-the-database-preview-environment)? It says _"All DB instances are deleted 60 days after you create them, along with any backups and snapshots."_, which might explain why it turned off.

Comment: Yes. They took a final snapshot then deleted the database. How can I use this final snapshot to get the data?

Comment: Perhaps you can launch another Preview database from that snapshot? It is strange that you have a snapshot, given that they say the database is deleted along with snapshots.

Comment: That's what gives me the error response I pasted above